# Compute "Amount" using values from tables

Tags: sql, database, oracle

I have the following tables already in my DB

```
EMP
    E_N E_NAM     E_RATE E_DEP
    --- ----- ---------- -----
    1   A            400      
    2   B            200 1    
    3   C            150 2    
    4   D            150 3    
    5   E            120 1    
    6   F            100 1    
    7   G            100 2    
    8   H             50 2    
    9   I             50 3    
    10  J             50 3    
    11  K            150 3  


WORKS
    E_NO PR_NO      HRS
    ---  ---   ----------
    2     1           10
    3     2           20
    5     1           20
    5     2           20
    5     3           20
    6     1           10
    6     2           10
```

I have to compute the amount billed to each project as AMOUNT, and that is the sum of the amount billed to the project by all employees who work on said project. The amount billed being E_RATE*HRS (product of HRS and E_RATE).

There are only 3 PR_NO: 1, 2 and 3.

I've tried this multiple times with no avail, I know that it has to be a nested query and the calculation to be shown AS AMOUNT, but no clue on how exactly to only display the 3 projects with the calculation already made.

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like simple join and aggregation:

```
select w.pr_no,
    sum(w.hrs * e.e_rate) as amount
from works w
join emp e on w.e_no = e.e_n
group by w.pr_no;
```

Comment: It worked beautifully thanks, but I really wish to understand the working behind this query.
What does the 4th line do exactly? It dismisses all values from table EMP that are not inside table WORK?

Comment: @John it joins the two tables based on the employee id. So, it will get us the rate for a given employee in a project.  Which we can use to find the total amount. If you want to understand how joins work, look for tutorials online.  There are plenty of resources available

Comment: Oh I get it, so it's like if (visually speaking) you added the extra columns from WORK into EMP but only those E_NO that are in WORK are used, the other discarded. Then it calculates the amount. Does that sound correct?

Comment: @John Yes. You could say that

Answer (score 0):

simple aggregate SUM() function after joining the tables

```
    --test data
    with EMP(e_no, e_name, e_rate, e_dep) as 
    (select     1,   'A',            400, null from dual union all     
    select     2,   'B',            200, 1    from dual union all 
    select     3,   'C',            150, 2     from dual union all
    select     4,   'D',            150, 3     from dual union all
    select     5,   'E',            120, 1     from dual union all
    select     6,   'F',            100, 1     from dual union all
    select     7,   'G',            100, 2     from dual union all
    select     8,   'H',             50, 2     from dual union all
    select     9,   'I',             50, 3     from dual union all
    select     10,  'J',             50, 3     from dual union all
    select     11,  'K',            150, 3   from dual),
    WORKS(e_no, pr_no, hrs) as 
    (select    2,     1,           10 from dual union all
    select    3,     2,          20 from dual union all
    select    5,     1,           20 from dual union all
    select    5,     2,           20 from dual union all
    select    5,     3,           20 from dual union all
    select    6,     1,           10 from dual union all
    select    6,     2,           10 from dual)
    -- actual query starts here
    select w.pr_no, sum(w.hrs*e.e_rate) as amount
    from   works w
     inner join emp e on (w.e_no = e.e_no)
    group by w.pr_no;


    "PR_NO"|"AMOUNT"
    1|5400
    2|6400
    3|2400
```

Comment: How is your answer any different from mine?

Comment: Thank you very much, but like I said to Gurwinder Singh I wanna understand the concept behind this, so using inner join you will only use values that are in both tables (w.e_no = e.e_no)?

Comment: I don't think it is really any different.  You just beat me to it.

Comment: Correct, inner join only returns records from each where there are matches.